# Dynamic color scheme changer for website

Tags: css

I'd like to build a web application that allows users to customize the colors by providing a color picker like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp) instead of a fixed number of preset stylesheets.

Are there any frameworks/libraries out there for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for Javascript solutions, check http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ for a jQuery solution, http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/colorpicker/ if you prefer YUI.

Answer (score -1):

If you are coding in PHP, this may be of interest to you.

http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: Smarty is a PHP template framework, it does not really help with this problem.

Comment: Actually it helps a lot, because Kedar can have the JS color picker for building a user preset, and then apply it via smarty, and not via JS. Why smarty? because it would make the whole "template" management and coding easy. Not convoluted.

Comment: My question was more about how to easily modify a site wide color scheme rather than about color picker widgets. I guess will have to look at a UI framework.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery UI Theme Roller? (http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/Themeroller) I know it'll only work for certain elements, but I guess it's a start.

Comment: Theme Roller looks promising. Thanks @Overkillica